# Replacing "." with "," when using numpy to write decimal numbers to file

Tags: python, numpy

Trying to replace "." with "," in the file that I am using numpy to write, but I only succeed reducing integers. How do I do that?

```
np.savetxt("C:\\Users\\jcst\\Desktop\\Private\\Python data\\train22.csv", ('%15.1f' % predicted_factor).replace(".", ","), delimiter=',')
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/jcst/PycharmProjects/Frafaldsanalyse/DefiningCatAndNumFeatures_4.py",
>   line 165, in 
>       np.savetxt("C:\Users\jcst\Desktop\Private\Python data\train22.csv", ('%15.1f' % predicted_factor).replace(".", ","),
>   delimiter=',') TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to
>   Python scalars

Comment: at least one of you problems is that you have the comma as your delimiter AND its in your data, so you have to wrap your data in `""`

Comment: `fmt` is supposed to be a valid python `%` formating string for one number.  The array you want to write is a separate parameter.  Reread the docs.

Comment: You may have to use the `locale` module to show a comma decimal point.  Don't use the same character as delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Ordinary float write with a `savetxt`:

```
In [44]: arr = np.arange(0,6,.34).reshape(6,3) 
In [51]: np.savetxt('test.txt',arr, fmt='%10.3f', delimiter=',')                
In [52]: cat test.txt                                                           
     0.000,     0.340,     0.680
     1.020,     1.360,     1.700
     2.040,     2.380,     2.720
     3.060,     3.400,     3.740
     4.080,     4.420,     4.760
     5.100,     5.440,     5.780
```

Editing this file after creation, replacing first the delimiter, and then the decimal point, is one option.

## locale

With the `locale` module it is possible to change the decimal point to comma (I'm assuming that's what you are trying to do with the `replace`).  But I can't find a way of using that directly with the `%` style of formatting that `savetxt` uses.

[locale.setlocale(LC_NUMERIC): how to make it work on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33952550/locale-setlocalelc-numeric-how-to-make-it-work-on-windows)

But it is possible use this localization with the newer `format` style, using 'n'`.  So rewriting`savetxt`to use`format`:

```
In [98]: fmt = '{:10.3n}'                                                       
In [99]: fmts = ';'.join([fmt]*3)+'\n'                                          
In [100]: fmts                                                                  
Out[100]: '{:10.3n};{:10.3n};{:10.3n}\n'
In [101]: with open('test1.txt','w') as f: 
     ...:     for row in arr: 
     ...:         f.write(fmts.format(*row)) 
     ...:                                                                       
In [102]: cat test1.txt                                                         
         0;      0,34;      0,68
      1,02;      1,36;       1,7
      2,04;      2,38;      2,72
      3,06;       3,4;      3,74
      4,08;      4,42;      4,76
       5,1;      5,44;      5,78
```

Earlier in the session I'd done

```
import locale    
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'en_DK.utf8')
```

I'm not familiar with `locale` but this seemed to be enough.  I don't have any special `locale` packages installed on my system.

## reading

Beware that `np.genfromtxt` will require a converter (to change the comma back to period).

```
In [145]: foo = lambda astr: float(astr.replace(b',',b'.'))                     
In [146]: np.genfromtxt('test1.txt',delimiter=';',converters={i:foo for i in ran
     ...: ge(3)})                                                               
Out[146]: 
array([[0.  , 0.34, 0.68],
       [1.02, 1.36, 1.7 ],
       [2.04, 2.38, 2.72],
       [3.06, 3.4 , 3.74],
       [4.08, 4.42, 4.76],
       [5.1 , 5.44, 5.78]])
```

## pandas

`pandas` though does have a `decimal` parameter:

```
In [133]: df = pd.read_csv('test1.txt',sep=';',decimal=',',header=None)         
In [134]: df                                                                    
Out[134]: 
      0     1     2
0  0.00  0.34  0.68
1  1.02  1.36  1.70
2  2.04  2.38  2.72
3  3.06  3.40  3.74
4  4.08  4.42  4.76
5  5.10  5.44  5.78
```

The pandas `csv` writer also takes a `decimal` parameter.

Maybe I should have looked at `pandas` right away!